# How to make a oauth authentication from salesforce mobile app? Web Tabs are not showing Allow Access? Pop up (iFrame Issue)

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, iframe, iot, web-tab

I have done a Device Flow Oauth using a ESP8266. Now i want to have the salesforce mobile app to authenticate my IoT device into salesforce.

When the IoT device generates a OTP(User_Code), I open login.salesforce.com/setup/connect and put in my OTP. Then the Allow Access Page opens up which I created using a connected app. Then I click on Allow to authenticate the device.

I want to do the same login process in salesforce mobile app.

So i created a web tab with hyperlink to login.salesforce.com/setup/connect  but it is facing iFrame issue

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is more likely that from a mobile app, you'll need to use `myDomain.com/setup/connect` instead of login.salesforce.com/setup/connect. Knowing more about how you have your OAuth2 configured and whether Salesforce is the idp would allow a more thorough diagnosis of your issue. Generally speaking though, mobile apps can only login to MyDomain URLs.